# Book - boy saves father by holding hand through transformations

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a fantasy book as a teenager (in the 80s, I think).  In it, a boy had to save his father.  All I can remember is that the dad was tied up between two posts...perhaps in a valley.  To save his father, the boy had to hold his hand no matter what.  His father turned into flame as well as a tiger and the boy endured and saved him.

Comment: Sounds like a fairytale I've read, actually. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @SQB - You're thinking of Tam Lin, I think. "They'll turn me to a bear so grim, 
And then a lion bold, 
But hold me fast, and fear me not, 
And ye shall love your child."  There are at least 3 dozen prose versions of the tale, and 20 or so song versions.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast So is that the answer?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Nope. The Tam Lin version goes back to at least the mid-1500s. The point is that the plot device used (holding on despite shape changes) does occur in fairy tales, but is unlikely an identifier for an 80s book.

Comment: @OP Are there any other identifying features you can remember? The cover art? Any letters or sounds in the author's name? Check out this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/75000) to help jog your memory.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember any further details...title, author, or otherwise.

Comment: OP, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I did not.